# 2 servers, 2 databases on each, 1st server 1st db master and 2nd slave, 2nd server 1st db slave, 2nd master, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-replication

I have 2 MySQL/MariaDB servers each of them with its own database and I would like to set up a continuous backup on each other via replication.

Is it possible to make 1 DB master and 1 slave on each one of the servers?

```
Server 1         Server 2

db1 (master)     db1 (slave)
db2 (slave)      db2 (master)
```

Or is there a better option to do it? But I would like to have ready-to-use DB(no dump files) in case of a failure of one of the servers so I can quickly switch to another.

Comment: Start with db1 master + slave - "easy binlog replication" then do it the other way around.
If the do not have conflicting databases or users, you could even run master+slave in same instance.

Comment: Sure you could do that. I'm a bit surprised that you didn't just do it. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Your specific use pattern is abnormal but feasible.  Search for "dual master" or "master-master".

Comment: @NiKiZe I see, so its like master-master but with different options in `binlog_do_db`, thanks, I set it up!

Comment: @RickJames I've heard about it, and after setting up I realized I can set different `binlog_do_db` values on each server so it will be exactly like I wanted! Thanks!